# Want to pass the array as parameter through xml to java file

Tags: java, arrays, xml, selenium-webdriver

I want to know how to pass the array as parameter in XML and then to use it later in Java file.

eg,

```
 // here i want to  pass both 'Asia' and 'Africa' as parameter.

<suite name="Parameterization Test Suite">    
<test name="Testing Parameterization">    
<parameter name="assetTypes" value=""/>    
<parameter name="instrumentTypes" value=""/>    
<parameter name="regions" value="'Asia','Africa'"/>
```

Passing Asia and Africa together in value is incorrect. Please help !!

Comment: Have you tried an xml parser?

Comment: You can pass multiple values in single parameter and splitting them using comma in your code and save it on to an array.

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni Not yet tried

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use parameter name as a tag name and define the values as sub tags of it?

```
<assetTypes>
  <assertType></assertType>
</assetTypes>
<instrumentTypes> 
   <instrumentType></instrumentType>
<regions>  
  <region value="Asia"/> 
  <region value="Africa"/>
</regions>
```

Comment: here <assetTypes> is not allowed here.. this error is appearing